# View image in new tab

Tags: c#, razor, devexpress

Good day

I have a issue with opening a .jpg in a new tab. I store .pdf and .jpg files on the server and have a Devexpress hyperlink in a grid that the clients can clink on to view the document. The files are in a virtual directory in IIS.

This is my code:

```
Html.DevExpress().HyperLink(settingsBtn =>
{
    settingsBtn.Name = "cb_" + c.KeyValue.ToString();

    if (DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "FileName") != null)
    {
        if (DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "FileName").ToString().EndsWith(".jpg") == true)
            settingsBtn.Properties.ImageUrl = "~/Content/GridImages/FileType_JPG.png";
        else
            settingsBtn.Properties.ImageUrl = "~/Content/GridImages/FileType_PDF.png";

        settingsBtn.NavigateUrl = "~/Documents/" + DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "FileName").ToString();
        settingsBtn.Properties.Target = "_blank";
    }

    settingsBtn.Width = 60;

}).GetHtml();
```

My problem is that when it is a .pdf it works 100% and the PDF opens in a new tab but when the file is a .jpg it takes me to the login page of the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `settingsBtn.Properties.Target = "_blank";` as you did for pdf file

Comment: settingsBtn.Properties.Target = "_blank" is for both pdf and jpg

Comment: No, its not. Look at your ifs :) In first you dont add this attribute, only when its pdf

Comment: Look closely. The if statement only set the image Url to display as the link. The navigation url is set afterwards.